# Tengo instalado PySide2, mi pregunta es por que no corre en Python 3.6

Tags: python, vscode, pyside2

Veran instale PySide2, pero cuando estoy importando las librerias en python 3.6 , el editor de codigo me las tacha, aunque el aplicativo sigue ejecutandose con normalidad, me gustaria saber como mejorar la compatibilidad entre PySide2 y Python, adicional a eso, en el caso de que PySide 2 este obsoleto, me podrian ayudar a encontrar otro framework de la comunidad para Qt.

[image: codigo de ventana sencillo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PySide2 es una librería escrita en C++ por lo que no hay ningun código python, y muchas IDEs no manejan el autocompletado de ese tipo de librerias, por lo que mi recomendación es que obvies eso. Quizas tu IDE tenga un paquete que solucione ese problema.

Comment: No lo habia pensado, voy a buscar ese paquete, en vs code. Gracias.

Comment: En Pycharm no ocurre...

Comment: @Saelyth como señale, el error depende de la IDE. Pycharm maneja esos elementos usando stubs

Comment: Solo lo comentaba como recomendación por si quiere intentar usar ese IDE.

Comment: @Saelyth entonces deberias señalarlo debajo de la pregunta como un comentario

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta, y estoy proximo en convertir los archivos generados en Qt Designer .ui a .py. Y mi respuesta es, obvio me toco pasar de largo a los tachones generados por python 3.6, por que sigue generando la ejecucion del archivo.py sin problemas.

Solo queria satisfacer una duda que tenia.